# How can I know the derivability of this function?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I've been working on this problem:

Study the differentiability of the following function $f$ at $x=0$:
$$
f=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\cos(3x)e^{3x} - e^x}{\ln(1+x)} & \text{if} x>0\\
2 &\text{if} x=0\\
\bigg(1+3\ln(2)\ln(1-x)\bigg)^{\dfrac{-1}{\sin(3x)}} &\text{if} - \pi /6 <x<0
\end{cases}
$$

---

**Attempt**:
$f$ is derivable at $x=0$ if: 
$$
\lim_{h\to0+} [f(0+h) - f(0)]/h  
= \lim_{h\to0-} [f(0+h) - f(0)]/h 
$$

Then if we aproach to $0+$ we get: 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0+} ([(\cos(3h)e^{3h} - e^h/ \ln (1+h)]-2)/h
$$
The limit of the first term: $(\cos(3h)e^{3h} - e^h / \ln (1+h)$ is $2$

So we got an indetermination 0/0 type

I rewrite the limit as: lim (cos(3h)e^(3h)-e^(h)-2ln(h+1))/ln(h+1)h

Then fixing the denominator to ln(h+1)^(1/h) we get 0/1 so the limit is 0

Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Then if we aproach to $0-$ we get: lim (1+3ln(2)ln(1-h)^(-1/sin(3h))-2/h

The limit of (1+3ln(2)ln(1-h))^(-1/sin(3h)) is 2

So we get again an indetermination 0/0 type

Using L´Hopital and logaritmic derivation we get:

lim (1/sin^2(3h))(-cos(3h))(3)ln(1+3ln(2)ln(1-h))-(1/sin(3h))(1/(1+3ln(2)ln(1-h))(3ln(2)/(1-h))(-1)^(-1/sin(3h)) as h approaches to 0-

I get another indetermination so...

And at this point I'm stuck.

Comment: Is the $$f(x)=\frac{\cos(3x)e^{3x}-e^x}{\ln(1+x)}$$

Comment: Please use mathjax for the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{\cos(3x)e^{3x}-e^x}{\ln(1+x)}=\frac{\cos(3x)e^{3x}-e^x}{x}\cdot \frac{x}{\ln(1+x)}.$$

The limits

$$ \lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\cos(3x)e^{3x}-e^x}{x}$$

and

$$ \lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x}{\ln(1+x)}$$

are easy to compute !